# Decoding '%40' back to '@' using jquery to populate input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url, decode

So I have this jquery script (thanks to a previous member right here) that takes the email or any other query string from the url and populates the value of the respective input fields on the page...

So... the form input is something like:

```
<input type="text" name="email" >
```

And the script is...

```
$(function () {

//grabs the entire query string
var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');

//extracts each field/value pair
query = query.split('&');

//runs through each pair
for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {

  //splits up the field/value pair into an array
  var field = query[i].split("=");

  //targets the field and assign its value
  $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);

}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
The url is encoded like this...

```
http://www.example.com/?email=some%40email.com
```

So in my code, how can I decode the '%40' back to '@' **before** it populates the values in the input fields? Any guidance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use plain javascript

```
decodeURIComponent('some%40email.com')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the insanely fast response! One thing, the some%40email.com is not hardcoded, it changes as per user input on a previous page. So how/where do I add the decodeURIcomponent in the code so that it will only change the %40 to @

Comment: I assume you set it using the `..val(field[1])` bit in your code. If so, just wrap that value so - .`..val(decodeURIComponent(field[1]))`

Comment: Woot woot! It's alive! :)

Comment: Try with `decodeURIComponent('email%3Dme%252Bformula%2540test.com')` , this is not valid and won't work

Answer (score 0):

decodeURIComponent('@')

decodeURIComponent('%40')